# how to create PKCS7 signedData structure with openssl or any other library with signing on smart card?

Tags: c++, openssl, smartcard, pkcs#7

i need to create PKCS7 signedData structure with signing performed on smart card. It is almost what openssl function PKCS7_sign does, except the signing. Maybe somebody can advice something for this question, i.e. how to do this with openssl or any other c/c++ crossplatform library.
As for openssl, it seems flags PKCS7_PARTIAL or PKCS7_STREAM of PKCS7_sign function can be usefull. If i use any of this flags i can get almost full PKCS7 structure. In this case the structure is full except that it does not contain "data" and "sign". So i need only add these elements. But i did not found the way how to do this. Does anybody know?

Comment: I do not know how you deal with smart card. Only thing OpenSSL needs is its parameters of the functions (certificates, private key and data). You have to extract certificate and private key from the smart card and supply to OpenSSL functions. However, if you cannot export the private key, then it is a problem. In my opinion, keep both of these parts (acting on smart card and using OpenSSL separate).

Comment: it is not possible to export private key from smart card.  It seems this can be a freaky workaround:  - generate new RSA key pair with public exponent =1;  - create PKCS7 structure with PKCS7_sing function and this key pair;  - get resulting PKCS7 structure with i2d_PKCS7_bio. This structure contains prepared to RSA decryption data instead of sign because of public exponent =1;  - send this data to smart-card for decryption and replace it with result.  But this requires own copy of some openssl functions because one of original functions contains key check.

Comment: Even it is not possible to export the private key, there must be some way to sign the data using that private key. for this, you may need to modify the source code of PKCS7_sign to have your control in signing part. Here, instead of using OpenSSL sign, you can call your function which will sign the data using smart card.

Comment: @dbasic, thanks. But problem is that it is not trivial, at least for me. There is no separate function for signing PKCS7 structure in openssl PKCS7_sign source code. Instead this operation divided on some functions like PKCS7_dataInit and PKCS7_dataFinal and also special kind of BIO is used.

Comment: I'm working on the same exact problem. So far, I've been trying to override the default signing method (using method = RSA_get_default_method and then overriding its method->flags and method->rsa_sign, to replace it with my smartcard signing method). Note that you should method->flags |= RSA_METHOD_FLAG_NO_CHECK .. I'm still trying, did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You generally do not want (or are technically blocked) from extracting the private key from a smartcard. As this is sort of the very point of a smartcard - a tamper proof bit of crypto memory and connected CPU that will never divulge your private key.

So instead you need to ask the chipcard nicely to do the signing for you.

OpenSSL can do this - but needs to know how to talk to the chipcard. That is generally done with an 'engine'. Most commonly a pkcs#11 of #15 is used for this - in conjunction with the vendors chipcard (reader) driver.

You then typically need to get the slot and key identifiers:

```
# Extracting slot, auth ids and key id's for later use/reference
#
set `pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so --list-slots | grep Slot | grep SCM`
SLOT=$2
set `pkcs15-tool --list-keys | grep ID`
AID=$4
KID=$7
```

After which you can do 'things' on the card:

```
/usr/bin/openssl << EOM
engine dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/Library/OpenSC/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so  -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre MODULE_PATH:opensc-pkcs11.so
XXX -engine pkcs11 -b-key slot_$SLOT-id_$KID -keyform engine  ....
EOM
```

One such thing can be signing a pkcs7. From code - pretty much do the same thing. I usually use the app/util convenience stuf from openssl it's apps directory to make live a bit easier.